# Get locale using graph api NOT getSignedRequest

Tags: facebook-graph-api, locale

I know it is possible to get the locale of the user with getSignedRequest, and it is possible to get the locale of the user with https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=locale once they have authorised the app.  But what is the equivalent graph api url that I can use before they have authorised the app?  All my code is with the graph api so I really dont want to have to switch now to using the whole facebook->getSignedRequest() stuff.  I can't find it anywhere but seems silly this functionality has not been provided in graph api?

Comment: You mean without an access token?  I'm not sure why you'd be able to see the locale without an authorization. Is that a public field?

Comment: You can with facebook->getSignedRequest yes. They don't need to have accepted the app.  But there appears to be no equivalent with the graph api, which makes no sense.

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $app_id,
        'secret' => $app_secret,
        'cookie' => true
));
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
print "get locale" .$signed_request['user']['locale'];

Getting the user's locale is vital for translating your app before they accept the permissions.  Otherwise why would they accept the permissions for an app in another language.

Comment: In the docs for http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ next to locale it says "No access_token required".  But it doesn't work when you try to call it with "me" and I can't call it with the user's id because they haven't authorised the app so I don't have it....!  So although it says it is public I don't see how it can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pick between using the [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) (which is sent in a POST request to all apps on Facebook) or authorizing the user.

If you don't do one of these, then you won't know what the Users ID is, so you will never be able to identify their locale.

The signed_request just requires you to be able to capture request data and then perform the parsing logic outlined in the doc linked to above - it doesn't require the use of any SDK or API, just the ability to read requests (most languages will be able to do this).